# "Cannot set column 'COLUMN_NAME'. The value violates the MaxLength limit of this column."

Tags: c#, excel, database, datatable

I have two data table which have some columns and i have two perform comparison of two data table rows.

Before performing the comparison of two data tables i am modifying the data type of one table thus making both data table of same data type.

Below is the code which i have used for modifying the data type of columns, however when i run the code i get following exception:

> "Cannot set column 'COLUMN_NAME'. The value violates the MaxLength
>   limit of this column."

I cannot change it to default string type if i do my comparison fails.

```
    public DataTable ModifyDataTableType(DataTable 
             refrenceDataTable,DataTable dataTable)

{
      DataTable dtCloned = dataTable.Clone();

        try{
            for(int i = 0;i<dtCloned.Columns.Count;i++)
            {
                dtCloned.Columns[i].DataType = 
                              refrenceDataTable.Columns[i].DataType;
            }

            dtCloned.AcceptChanges();
            foreach(DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                //Exception is thrown here
                dtCloned.ImportRow(dr);   
            }

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info,"Exception message:- "+ex.Message);
        }
        return dtCloned;
}
```

I should be able to get the data table with rows of referenced data table data type

Comment: What type of database?  How are the tables defined?  What's in the row you're trying to import?

Comment: I have two data table one from Oracle DB and second i have converted  an excel sheet to data table.                                                                                             
Row in data table consists of different data types (int,string,decimal.. etc)

Comment: I Tried to debug and got the know the exception occurs only for the columns where data is not available (null) however not for string column data type.                                 if any one can help me to find out where the problem exists or any workaround it will great.