# Cannot update data using DataAdapter and DataTable

Tags: c#, dataset, dataadapter

I have been writing a Windows Forms app that can connect to a database in VS 2017 community. One of tables (named Student) of my database has schema that looks like this:
[image]
and its data:
[image]
I have written a function that can update data to my table above. It looks like this:

```
 try
    {
       DataTable mytable= new DataTable();
       using (SqlConnection connection =
                    new SqlConnection(@"Server=DESKTOP-O6BPUKE\SQLEXPRESS;
                     Database=MyDatabase; 
                     Integrated Security=SSPI"))
        using (SqlCommand command =
                    new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Student;", connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        using (SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
                {
                    adapter.FillSchema(mytable, SchemaType.Source);
                    adapter.Fill(mytable);
                    DataRow[] dt = mytable.Select("MaSV = 'SV04'");
                    dt[0]["TenSV"] = "Messi";
                    dt[0]["Email"] = "mess@gmail.com";
                    dt[0]["MaKH"] = "KH01";
                    mytable.Rows.Add(dt);
                    adapter.Update(mytable);
                }
     MessageBox.Show("Update success!");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
   }
```

when i run my app, an error occurred:

[image]
I referred the question of [Mohit Talreja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762577/cannot-set-column-column-name-the-value-violates-the-maxlength-limit-of-this) but did not find any solution. Please help me.

Comment: Thank everyone, i see my problem that is the following line: mytable.Rows.Add(dt). Deleting it because i want to update, not insert.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update sql server table you need to use an sql command:

```
    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Server=DESKTOP-O6BPUKE\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI")
    {
                connection.Open();
                string sql =  "INSERT INTO Student(klant_id,naam,voornaam) VALUES(@TenSV,@Email,@MaKH)";
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection)) 
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TenSV", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = "Messi";  
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = "mess@gmail.com";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MaKH", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = "KH01";
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                }
    }
```